# The production of what substances has a similar environmental impact to Chlorinated paraffins?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am currently conducting a Life Cycle Assessment (LCA) study in which the final product consists to a large part of Chlorinated paraffins. However, I cannot find Chlorinated paraffins as a *process* in available LCA background data.

Therefore, I am asking what other substances are likely to have a similar environmental impact during the production compared to Chlorinated paraffins (and are maybe even more commonly used so that the likelihood to find them as an existing LCA data set is high)?

Comment: Terminology might be a problem. You could try searching for chlorinated hydrocarbons or chlorinated saturated hydrocarbons or something similar.